# Windows 2000 mrxsmb.sys issue while using network shares

Tags: drivers, network-shares, windows-server-2008-r2, windows-2000

At my job, we use some old FTR (ForTheRecord) Recording devices.  These devices are actually Windows 2000 computers with audio recording hardware attached.  These devices encountered a few issues with autologin as a particular user name was deleted, but I have since resolved those.  However, one of them is having a problem.  Every time a large file is saved to network storage (we have shares set up for easy transfer onto a Server 2008 R2 file server) the recording device reboots.  There's no BSOD, but there are dump files that indicate a possible issue with mrxsmb.sys that is described in this article: http://support.microsoft.com/kb/831128.  I downloaded these fix files, but it didn't work.  I'm not entirely sure I did what needs to be done, and no documentation comes with this hotfix.  It comes with two files: Windows2000-KB831128-x86-ENU.exe and WINDOWS2000-KB831128-X86-ENU-Symbols.exe.  The normal one runs a standard install, but the "Symbols" executable just extracts four files: mrxsmb.dbg, mrxsmb.pdb, rdbss.dbg, rdbss.pdb.  Since file system drivers aren't really my forte, the question is am I supposed to do something with these files?  If this isn't the issue, does anyone know of conflicts like this when transferring files between Windows 2000 and Server 2008 R2 servers?

For what it's worth, there is also a share on the Windows 2000 PCs.  If I access this share from a different PC and pull the files off that way, no errors happen.  The error only occurs if I initiate the transfer from the Windows 2000 PC.

Comment: the debug files are used by Windbg to help you to debug crashes. You must use the Windows2000-KB831128-x86-ENU.exe. But, Win2000 is out of support, so stop using it.

Comment: I know, but due to the equipment and software on these boxes, they're kind of tied to Windows 2000.  Trust me, as soon as we can afford to, a hardware upgrade is in order.  Thanks for the tip on the files.